# Implement Remember Me utilizing Cookie with expiration time instead of LocalStorage

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, blazor

I have been trying to get this working now for quite a some time but can't figure out how to do it properly. I am able to implement Rememeber Me with LocalStorage. However I want to implement Remember Me functionality with JWT using cookie where I would be able to set expiration time. I think I have messed up the login logic? Can somebody point out what is wrong here?

I can also add other parts from my application if necessary.

AuthorizeController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel login)
{
  ApplicationUser user = await this.SignInManager.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(login.Email);

  if (user == null)
  {
    List<string> errors = new List<string>();
    errors.Add("No such user has been found.");
    return BadRequest(new LoginResult
    {
      Successful = false,
      Errors = errors,
    });
  }

  bool emailConfirmed = await this.UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user);

  if (!emailConfirmed)
  {
    List<string> errors = new List<string>();
    errors.Add("Email not confirmed.");
    return BadRequest(new LoginResult
    {
      Successful = false,
      Errors = errors,
    });
  }

  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result =
    await this.SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(login.Email, login.Password, login.RememberMe, false);

  if (!result.Succeeded)
  {
    List<string> errors = new List<string>();
    errors.Add("Email and password are invalid.");
    return BadRequest(new LoginResult
    {
      Successful = false,
      Errors = errors,
    });
  }

  IList<string> roles = await this.SignInManager.UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

  List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
  {
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, login.Email)
  };

  ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
  ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
  AuthenticationProperties props = new AuthenticationProperties
  {
    IsPersistent = true,
    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1)
  };

  // to register the cookie to the browser
  this.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, props).Wait();

  foreach (string role in roles)
  {
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
  }

  SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.Configuration["JwtSecurityKey"]));
  SigningCredentials creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
  DateTime expiry = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(this.Configuration["JwtExpiryInDays"]));

  JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    this.Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
    this.Configuration["JwtAudience"],
    claims,
    expires: expiry,
    signingCredentials: creds
  );

  return Ok(new LoginResult
  {
    Successful = true,
    Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
  });
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
        ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtAudience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtSecurityKey"]))
      };
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
     {
       options.Cookie.Name = "MySpecialCookie";
       options.LoginPath = "/login";
       //options.LogoutPath = "/Home/Index";
       //options.AccessDeniedPath = "AccessDenied";
       options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
       options.SlidingExpiration = true; // the cookie would be re-issued on any request half way through the ExpireTimeSpan
                                         //options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(5);
       options.EventsType = typeof(CookieAuthEvent);
     });
  services.AddScoped<CookieAuthEvent>();

  services.AddAuthorization(config =>
  {
    config.AddPolicy(Policies.IsAdmin, Policies.IsAdminPolicy());
    config.AddPolicy(Policies.IsUser, Policies.IsUserPolicy());
  });

  services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
  {
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
      context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
  });
```

On Client side I am currently using AuthorizeApi with LocalStorage. This is working but I want to move this to Cookie.

AuthorizeApi.cs:

```
public async Task<LoginResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
{
  //var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(LoginModel), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await this.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Authorize/Login", loginModel);
  LoginResult result = await responseMessage.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<LoginResult>();

  if (result.Successful)
  {
    if (loginModel.RememberMe)
    {
      await this.LocalStorage.SetItemAsync("MySpecialToken", result.Token);
    }

    ((ApiAuthenticationStateProvider)this.AuthenticationStateProvider).MarkUserAsAuthenticated(result.Token);
    this.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result.Token);

    return result;
  }

  return result;
}
```

ApiAuthenticationStateProvider.cs:

```
public void MarkUserAsAuthenticated(string token)
{
  ClaimsPrincipal authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(token), "jwt"));
  Task<AuthenticationState> authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));
  NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an older project I created custom authentication that used cookies to store the session identifier.

The process was simple. Start by adding a service to house the tokens for the current user session, that will probably be sent to your API, or alternatively update your injected `HttpClient` right after authentication or on your `MainLayout` once you've retrieved the value from the cookie:

```
if (!httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("SessionID"))
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SessionID", await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("MyJs.Cookies.Get", "SessionID"));
```

Then on your `MainLayout` check if the cookie has a value before you navigate to authentication. To do this, I used the following JavaScript:

```
window.MyJs = {
    Cookies: {
        Set: function (name, value, date) {
            var d = new Date(date);
            var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
        },
        Get: function (name) {
            name = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        },
        Remove: function (name) {
            RadixTrie.Cookies.Set(name, "", "01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC");
        }
    }
}
```

Do the check in MainLayout like this:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
    if (firstRender)
    {
        ...
        var sessionID = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("MyJs.Cookies.Get", "SessionID");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sessionID))
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Auth/Login", true);
        ...
    }
}
```

Once you've authenticated, you can just set the cookie:

```
internal async Task Login() {
    ...
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("MyJs.Cookies.Set", "SessionID", loginResponse.Token, loginResponse.Expires);
    //{loginResponse.Token:string} {loginResponse.Expires:datetime}
    ...
}
```

#### EDIT:

I wasn't satisfied with this answer and took some time to consider alternatives. I don't have a fully coded solution, but a better way of implementing a token for authentication, and in your case to keep a session live, would be using [`Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header in your responses from your API.

I suggest creating `middleware` to handle the reading and resetting of the token.

But let's start with the login. Once a user authenticated, you can update the response in your endpoint like:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel login)
{
    ...
    Response.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", $"SessionID={Guid.NewGuid()}; Expires={DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss") + " UTC"}; HttpOnly"); //Valid for 1 month, HttpOnly
    ...
    return Ok();
}
```

It would be a good idea to make the token and cookie string generation reusable at this point. Consider encryption too.

Thereafter, add `middleware` to your API and on each request read the cookie to get the token:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    ...
    context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("SessionID", out string sessionID);
    ...
    await _next(context);
    ...
    //Reset the token after each request for improved security
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", $"SessionID={Guid.NewGuid()}; Expires={DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss") + " UTC"}; HttpOnly"); //Valid for 1 month, HttpOnly
}
```

#### EDIT 2:

If a cookie is reset and there are asynchronous work being done using the API, some requests might fail if a request is made just after the cookie change before being updated. This is a very small window and should be low in chance. I will take some time in the future to test this theory and update this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think there should be some native way of implementing this without using custom made javascript?

Comment: Shouldn't these types of cookies be http-only?

Comment: Ok, if there is no native way to deal with JWT and custom made JavaScript is the only way to go, I guess this must be an answer then. I am not highest professional in Blazor and asp.net world. How much insecure website will be without JWT using asp.net native solutions?

Comment: @10101, I've had some time to think, don't think this is the best solution. I can guess, but have not implemented something. You can let the API control all tokens by using a `Set-Cookie` response header after login. And in return read that cookie from subsequent requests. I did a brief test, and it should work. Another improvement would be to reset that cookie after each request.

Comment: @10101, give me some time and I'll update my answer here.

Comment: @10101, answer has been updated

Comment: @10101, if you want me to extend the answer with JWT type logic, let me know.

Comment: Thank you! I will check it during the week and come back if there will be additional questions. Thank you for support!